# Indicial notation for contracted product $\textbf{P:V}$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, notation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I was wondering what is the indicial notation of the contracted product. In plasma physics, I encountered $\nabla\cdot (\textbf{P:V})$ (**P** is the pressure tensor and **V** the velocity vector). I suppose that $\textbf{P:V}$ must be a vector, but do someone know the exact notation ? (e.g. for tensorial product $(\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v})_{ij}=u_iv_j$)

Comment: Encountered where?

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Méthode_de_Chapman-Enskog at "équation d’évolution" just to cite one examples, but in some papers too.

Comment: That's almost certainly $(\mathbf P:\mathbf V)_i = P_{ij} V_j$ but it's probably better to wait for someone with direct subject-matter knowledge to confirm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a colon mean in hydrodynamics equations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167524/)

Comment: I've also seen the colon notation indicate the dyadic product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, $A:B$ denotes the "double dot product", also known as the "double inner product" of two tensors of order at least two, formed by contracting the last two indices of the first tensor with the first two indices of the second tensor. There are differing conventions as to the order of the indices used, e.g. whether the definition for order two tensors is

$$A:B=A_{ij}B_{ij}$$

or

$$A:B=A_{ij}B_{ji}\ \ ,$$

where the summation convention is being used. The double dot product is often used with symmetric tensors, in which case it doesn't matter which of the above definitions is used.

The [French Wikipedia web page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Chapman-Enskog) mentioned in a comment to the question appears to be using the colon to mean the same thing as the (single) dot product, i.e. using it to mean

$$P:V=P_{ij}V_j\ \ ,$$

but that appears to be an incorrect use of notation on that web page. A normal use of notation would be

$$P\cdot V=P_{ij}V_j\ \ .$$

Comment: +1 I was also considering that it was incorrect use of nation. The correct term for work done on the fluid by pressure as should be used in the equation is $\vec{\nabla}\cdot(p\vec{v})$ where $p$ is the pressure scalar. This can be rewritten as $\vec{\nabla}\cdot(p\boldsymbol{I}\cdot\vec{v})=\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\boldsymbol{P}\cdot\vec{v})$ where $\boldsymbol{P}=p\boldsymbol{I}$ and $\boldsymbol{I}$ is the identity tensor.