# Wave equation in two different forms (2nd order, 1st order): Which of the two should I use and when?

Tags: waves, elasticity, solid-mechanics

I am studying elastic waves in solids. Depending on paper or documents, the wave equation is written in two different forms.

The first form is in the second order PDE

$$ \rho \frac{{{\partial ^2}{\mathbf{u}}}}{{\partial {t^2}}} = \nabla  \cdot \left( {{\mathbf{C}}:\nabla {\mathbf{u}}} \right) .$$

The second form is in the first order PDE

$$ \rho \frac{{\partial {\mathbf{v}}}}{{\partial t}} = \nabla  \cdot {\mathbf{S}} .$$

where p is density, u displacement, v velocity, S stress tensor, C elasticity tensor (stiffness).

Personally, I am more familiar with the second-order form. I think people in geophysics tend to use the second form (first-order).

What is the advantage of using the first-order form or the second-order form?
Is there a special situation to choose either one?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they not the same equation in different notation?

Comment: What is $C:\nabla u$?

Comment: @mikestone I think they are the same mathematically except for the order of derivative.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero it is a dot product between the second-order tensors. 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/167526/348152
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303561/824742

Comment: The order of the derivative is the same as ${\bf v}$ is the derivative of ${\bf u}$.