Meaning of colon symbol $:$ in optics
When I was reading some early days nonlinear optics paper/textbooks (particularly between 1960-1985), I often see expressions such as:
$\chi^{(2)}:\textbf{E}\textbf{E}$
or
$\nabla\textbf{E}:\partial \textbf{Q}/\partial t$.
For example, in equation (2.5) and (2.6) of the paper:
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.130.919
What is the name of this operation and how it is mathematically defined? It resembles a tensor product.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167524/2451

@Qmechanic Thank you!

The symbol $:$ is nothing but a double contraction of Cartesian tensors:
$$\chi^{(2)}: {\bf EE}= \sum_{i,j =1}^3\chi^{(2)}_{ij}E_i E_j$$
One of them must be symmetric to avoid ambiguities in the choice of summed indices.
The single dot denotes a contraction.
